# Html5 PWA application on .NET Maui using WebView: where to place source?

Tags: .net, maui

I've an html5 pwa application (html+css+js).

I want to 'embed' on a .NET Maui new application.

In which folder i have to place files ?

Where can I user WebView to load that app ?

Answer (score 1):

According to [WebView - Display a local HTML file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/webview?pivots=devices-android#display-a-local-html-file),you need to set the Build Action property of your html, css, and js files to `MauiAsset`.

> To display a local HTML file, add the file to the `Resources\Raw` folder of your app project and set its build action to `MauiAsset`.

For specific steps, you could refer to the following minimization example.

Step 1. I created 3 files named test.html, test.css and test.js in `Resources\Raw` folder and set their build action to `MauiAsset`.

Step 2. Populate layout in HTML and reference CSS and js files:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <p>Test for HTML loading.</p>
        <button onclick="testFun()">alert</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Step 3. In the Maui page, you could reference this HTML file directly.
`<WebView HeightRequest="400" WidthRequest="400" Source="test.html">`

After that, you could build the project and find that the HTML, CSS, JS files work as expected.